# Can I use C# 7.3 with .Net Framework 4.6.1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generic-constraints, c#-7.3

I'm interested in `enum` generic constraints, but when I'm switching language version for project on **Build → Advanced** I'm still getting error «*not available in C#5; please use language version 7.3 or greater*» even after reopening the project.
Project type is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: The answer is yes but your compiler version must support c#7. What compiler version/vs version are you using?

Comment: this depends on your C# compiler version rather than your .NET version

Comment: How I can find version of current compiler and install needed one?

Comment: which version of VS are you using?

Comment: It's a VS 2017, version 15.8.4.

Comment: THen it support it assuming you did all the updates. check the project properties and select 7.3 as langauge version.

Comment: If the compiler can tell you that you use the wrong version then you have the right compiler.  But not the right version.  Change this build setting for both the Debug and the Release configuration, combobox at the top of the Build tab.

Comment: Already, but still getting an error.

Comment: You are doing *something* wrong, but it is unguessable from the question.  Try this first on a new project.  Next ask a co-worker to look over your shoulder, he might see something.

Comment: Looks like restarting VS helps. Sorry for fake alarm, guys. upd.: Oh no, it not. Again error.

Comment: Installed *Compilers* and *CodeDom.DotNetPlatform*, then changed in web.config `system.codedom → compilers → compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"` property `langversion` to `7.3` and all works.

Comment: When dealing with ASP.NET, that does dynamic compilation at runtime, you have two compilers in play, the one used by msbuild/Visual Studio/whatever, and the one running at runtime, your package installation dealt with the runtime compiler, you likely already had the right IDE compiler.

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy Please post that as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` packages from Nuget, then changed in **web.config** `system.codedom → compilers → compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"` property `langversion` to `7.3`, reloaded project and all worked.

Comment: not working for me, already updated both `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` to the latest version which is `v3.6.0` at the moment. The `langversion` is correctly set to `7.3` but still cannot build the project.